# Issue with Getx 4.6.1

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

After adding a get:^4.6.1 I got the below error.

Code:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter web One',
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Error:

```
  const CupertinoApp({

        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/get-4.6.1/lib/get_navigation/src/root/get_material_app.dart:275:17: Error: No named parameter with the name 'useInheritedMediaQuery'.
                useInheritedMediaQuery: useInheritedMediaQuery,
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app.dart:217:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const MaterialApp.router({

        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/get-4.6.1/lib/get_navigation/src/root/get_material_app.dart:322:17: Error: No named parameter with the name 'useInheritedMediaQuery'.
                useInheritedMediaQuery: useInheritedMediaQuery,

                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app.dart:166:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const MaterialApp({
        ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and also if I try to downgrade getx version 4.6.1 to 4.3.8 still i am getting the same error and in the error, it shows **get-4.6.1** version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above problem is happening in `get` version >= 4.6.0. Use the exact version below 4.6.0 withing using `^` sign, which upgrades the package to the maximum compatible version.

In `pubspec.yaml` use `get` package like below:

```
get: 4.5.1     #Don't use ^
```